# Asp.Net Core Include values of FK of another FK

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, include

I have 3 Models, 3 tables in DB (created with EF migrations):

```
public class Announce {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Location Location { get; set;}
        public int LocationId { get; set; }
}

public class Location {   
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public District District { get; set; }
    public string DistrictId { get; set; }
}

public class District {   
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and a Dto class :

```
public class AnnounceForListDto {
            public int Id { get; set; }            
            public string LocationName { get; set; }
            public string DistrictName{ get; set; }
    }
```

And in AutoMapperProfile :

```
CreateMap<District, AnnounceForListDto>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.DistrictName, opt =>
                {
                    opt.MapFrom(dis => dis.Name);
                });
```

And I want to getAnnounces as :

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Announce>> GetAnnounces()
        {
            var announces = await _context.Announce
                    .Include(prop => prop.Photos)
                    .Include(prop => prop.Location)
                    .ToListAsync();
            return announces;
        }
```

I need to include the District Name (or District Id, because I use AutoMapper to equalise DistrictName from AnnounceForListDto with District.Name) in my list.

I tried something as .Include(prop => prop.Location.District.Name), but get an error, "Include can use only one "dot").

Maybe `.ThenInclude(Location => Location.District)` this help and I wrong in my Dto declaration?

My Dto is used in Controller :

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAnnounces()
        {
            var announces = await _repo.GetAnnounces();

            var announcesToReturn = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<AnnounceForListDto>>(announces);

            return Ok(announcesToReturn);
        }
```

Comment: Where is your Dto used?

Comment: I edited my post, added the GetAnnounces() method from Controller. _repo is istance of my IAnnounceRepository

Comment: my ef migrations fu**ed me :))) doesn't create relation between Location and District. I'll try again.

Comment: Rather than edit the question to add the solution, post it as answer! [Answering your own question is not forbidden](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250208/4733879), but [officially encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). (there is even an option to answer the question directly at the [Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) page)

Comment: Note that `public string DistrictId` in `Location` cannot be used as FK to `public int Id` property of `District` (different types)

Comment: Due of this, duplicate DistrictId in database. Escaped from my attention...thanks. there must be an int, not string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved :** 
     Create relation between Location and District

then, my Repo method :

```
var announces = await _context.Announce
                    .Include(prop => prop.Photos)
                    .Include(prop => prop.Location)
                        .ThenInclude(prop => prop.District)
                    .ToListAsync();
            return announces;
```